# LaTeX output in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I have defined a function in Sympy which outputs a string of symbols: various partial derivatives  of a function. I want the output of the function to tell me which partial derivatives the various entries in the list represent.

For example, instead of the function just outputting (1,3,xy, 2x) I'd like it to output the following LaTeX: $f_{xx} = 1, f_{xy} =3, f_{yx} = xy, f_{yy} = 2x$ (and preferably as a vertical list as opposed to a horizontal list.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not automatically, but it would be pretty easy to write Python code to convert one to the other.

Comment: @TimRoberts Any help with writing such a Python code? I still can't get it to work

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with %-formatting or `.format` or even simple string concatenation but f-strings are probably the most syntactically concise.  A simple function like so should do the trick; the trick is to use {{ and }} to escape the literal brackets

```
def latex_format_pderivs(xx, xy, yx, yy):
   inputs = ['xx', 'xy', 'yx', 'yy']
   outputs = [xx, xy, yx, yy]
   expr = ', '.join(f'f_{{{inp}}} = {out}' for inp, out in zip(inputs, outputs))
   return f'${expr}$'

>>>  latex_format_pderivs(1, 3, 'xy', '2x')
 '$f_{xx} = 1, f_{xy} = 3, f_{yx} = xy, f_{yy} = 2x$'
```